# Hibernate Foreign Key Insert doesn't Work

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want to insert some products in `product` table using Hibernate.

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `brand_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `info` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `fullname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_product_2_idx` (`category_id`),
  KEY `FK_product_1_idx` (`brand_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_product_1` FOREIGN KEY (`brand_id`) REFERENCES `brand` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_product_2` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1315 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Above is my product table. I first query for `brand` and `category` like this:

```
public Brand getMyBrand(){
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    Brand result = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Query hql = session.createQuery
                ("FROM Brand B WHERE B.name= :name");
        hql.setParameter("name", "unknown");
        result = (Brand) hql.uniqueResult();
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then I use this piece of code to save the product:

```
public int testInsert(){
    Product product = new Product(getUnknownCategory(),getUnknownBrand()
            ,"test1","test1","test1");
    return insertSingleProduct(product);
}

public int insertSingleProduct(Product product){
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    int result = -1;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        result = (Integer) session.save(product);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
        return result;
    }
}
```

but I end up with the following error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'brand_id' doesn't have a default value
```

which means it can't find the brand in the brand table!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have understood the reason as I faced this once.
The error is telling you everything. Your column brand_id does not have a default value. 
So during insertion DB is not able to figure what to insert..
Now you have three options:
1. Add a default value to the column brand_id Using -

```
ALTER TABLE `xxx` ALTER `brand_id` SET DEFAULT NULL
```

2. Supply some value to the supplier_id column during insertion.Not the best thing as requires effort but depends on the scenario. Make generator class as assigned if you choose this.
3. Add an auto increment to the column and add a primary key to it using the code. I think this will be good for you but please recheck :-

   ALTER TABLE `xxx` CHANGE `brand_id` `brand_id` INT(10)AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;

Hope this helps..